# fastStructure: Argument 'pi' has incorrect type

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to perform an analysis using fastStructure. I managed to install it on Ubuntu 20.04.6, but when I try to run it with the test dataset, it throws the following error:

```
python structure.py -K 3 --input=test/testdata --output=test/testoutput_simple --full --seed=100
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/fastStructure/structure.py", line 176, in <module>
    Q, P, other = fastStructure.infer_variational_parameters(G, params['K'], \
  File "fastStructure.pyx", line 101, in fastStructure.infer_variational_parameters
    E = mlhood.marginal_likelihood(G, psi, pi)
TypeError: Argument 'pi' has incorrect type (expected allelefreq.AlleleFreq, got allelefreq.AlleleFreq)
```

As a result, the output file testoutput_simple.3.log is empty, and the others missing.

I can't figure out what the issue is.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: is this the project? https://github.com/rajanil/fastStructure (it's very old and has a number of ancient issues) how did you install it? (just `git pull`?) you'll need to build `fastStructure.pyx` with cython

Comment: Yes, is that project (github.com/rajanil/fastStructure) and yes, I compiled it using Cython. I had some issues in between, but I thought I had resolved them. What puzzled me is having trouble running the test data, I would have expected to encounter issues with my own data.